# Using _BitScanReverse64

Tags: c++

How to use

```
_BitScanReverse64(unsigned long * Index,  unsigned __int64 Mask)
```

in order to find a first position set to 1 in integer?

Comment: what specifically don't you understand in the docs and the example for that function [at msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbxyd7zd(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: @Mat I don't understand how Mask param must be set (to what value)

Comment: @Oli thanks, I wish they could name it somewhat less confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
   unsigned __int64 mask = some_value;
   unsigned long index;
   unsigned char isNonzero = _BitScanReverse64(&index, mask);
   if (!isNonzero) {
      // index variable contains index of the first bit set to 1
   }
```

Comment: Yeah, you'll get a position of the first bit set to 1 in mask variable.